# Express - Validation for Patch Requests

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I'm a front-end dev trying to create the rest api for my project with Node/Express.

I'm using `Joi` for validtion. I'm curios how can I `PATCH` request routes. I cannot use `Joi` because it says `this field is required`.

so I'm wondering how can I validate `PATCH` request routes. because I don't know what data I'll get. what could go wrong by using `req.body` without validation?

```
export const updateAccount = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  let values = req.body;

  if (req.method === 'PUT') {
    values = await accountSchema.validateAsync(req.body);
  }

  const account = await Account.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, values, {
    new: true,
  });

  if (!account) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Account not found' });
  }

  res.status(200).json(account);
});
```

Comment: havent spent any time outside of postman with joi, but here is an example of how to do it with express validator https://github.com/alilland/nodejs-api/blob/master/src/routes/registerRoutes.js

Comment: having come from other languages to nodejs its highly important to validate every value received if you can, otherwise you are just asking for trouble. But, you will find that most new javascript developers and many of the ones that write blog posts do not validate their payloads, which is dangerous. The biggest concerns for software developers exist here, https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/ and XSS attacks are what you are attempting to avoid by validating fields.

Comment: thanks! looks like I have to create another schema just for patch requests to validate the user input instead of using `req.body` without validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @aliland mentioned and also following **Never trust user input**. I've created a new `Joi` schema just for patch requests. because with the current schema it was complaining about the required fields.

my schema:

```
const accountSchemaForPatchRequests = Joi.object({
  firstName: Joi.string().min(3).max(30),
  lastName: Joi.string(),
  email: Joi.string().email(),
  password: Joi.string().min(8),
});
```

and controller:

```
export const updateAccount = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  let values = req.body;

  if (req.method === 'PUT') {
    values = await accountSchema.validateAsync(req.body);
  } else {
    values = await accountSchemaForPatchRequests.validateAsync(req.body);
  }

  const account = await Account.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, values, {
    new: true,
  });

  if (!account) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Account not found' });
  }

  res.status(200).json(account);
});
```